# How to a create recursive variable per group in data frame?

Tags: r, for-loop, recursion, dplyr, sapply

I have a data set with multiple observations of a clinical outcome for each patient. The length between these time points is variable. I want to create a "roving baseline score" variable for the clinical outcome, that changes every time an increase or a decrease of the score is confirmed at the first time point that is at least 90 days ahead.

I have created an example data frame with observations for two patients (patient 1 has 6 observations, patient 2 only has 2 observations):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
patID  = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"),     
time_point = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-09-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-05-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-10-01", "2021-04-01")),
score = c("300", "100", "100", "100", "200", "200", "600", "400", "300", "200", "200", "100", "400", "300"))
```

The vector with the baseline score should result in the following:

```
baseline = c("300", "300", "300", "100", "100", "200", "600", "600", "300", "300", "300", "200", "200", "300")
```

- Explanation: the score of patient 1 decreases at time point 2 from 300 to 100. This decrease can be confirmed at time point 4, since this is the closest time point that is at least 90 days ahead. Thus, the new baseline at time point 4 is 100. At time point 6, an increase in the score (with respect to the latest baseline) is confirmed and we obtain a new baseline of 200.
  Patient 2 only has two time points and therefore a change in the baseline cannot be confirmed.

I have tried creating the variable using a for loop, but I don't know how to make it such that it is done for each patient separately.

EDIT: I tried to write the code as following using sapply, but I get the error "argument is of length 0"

```
df_baseline <- df %>%
group_by(patID) %>%
mutate(baseline = lag(score, default = first(score)),
     closest_index_90 = sapply(1:n(), function(i) {
       valid_indices <- which(date[i]+90 <= date[(i+1):n()])
       if (length(valid_indices)>0) {return(first(valid_indices) + i)} 
       else {return(NA)}
     }),
     baseline = sapply(1:n(), function(i) {
       if (score[i:closest_index_90[i]] > baseline[i - 1] | score[i:closest_index_90[i]] < baseline[i - 1]) {return(score[which.min(abs(score[i:closest_index_90[i]]-baseline[i-1]))])}
     else {return(baseline[i-1])}}))
```

I am relatively new to R so my skills with for loops and sapply functions are limited. I have looked through many questions asked on here but none seemed to answer my question specifically. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using `purrr::accumulate2`

```
df %>%
group_by(patID) %>%
mutate(
closest_index_90 = sapply(1:n(), function(i) {
   valid_indices <- which(date[i]+90 <= date[(i+1):n()])
   if (length(valid_indices)>0) {return(first(valid_indices) + i)} 
   else {return(NA)}
 }),
baseline = accumulate2(
   time_point,
   replace_na(closest_index_90, max(i)),
   \(b, i, r) {
   if (b>max(score[i:r])) {max(score[i:r]}
   else if (b<min(score[i:r])) {min(score[i:r]}
   else b
   }, .init = score[[1]]
   )[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a different approach using a rolling join to find the closest match with a gap of at least 90 days. Needs testing with more data, but see if this helps.

I get 200 for the last row as neither the increase to 400 nor the decrease to 300 have been confirmed.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

df <- tribble(
  ~patID, ~tmp,         ~date, ~score, ~desired,
     1,       1, "2020-01-01",    300,      300,
     1,       2, "2020-05-01",    100,      300,
     1,       3, "2020-06-01",    100,      300,
     1,       4, "2020-09-01",    100,      100,
     1,       5, "2021-01-01",    200,      100,
     1,       6, "2021-05-01",    200,      200,
     2,       1, "2020-01-01",    600,      600,
     2,       2, "2020-05-01",    400,      600,
     3,       1, "2020-01-01",    300,      300,
     3,       2, "2020-02-01",    200,      300,
     3,       3, "2020-03-01",    200,      300,
     3,       4, "2020-06-01",    100,      200,
     3,       5, "2020-10-01",    400,      200,
     3,       6, "2021-04-01",    300,      300
  ) |> 
  mutate(date = ymd(date))

change_df <- df |>
  mutate(
    change = if_else((score < lag(score) &
      slide_dbl(lead(score), \(.x) min(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .after = Inf) <= score) |
      (score > lag(score) &
         slide_dbl(lead(score), \(.x) min(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .after = Inf) >= score),
    score, NA
    ),
    conf_after = if_else(score != lag(score), date + days(90), NA),
    .by = patID
  ) |>
  select(patID, conf_after, change) |>
  drop_na()

df |>
  left_join(change_df, join_by(patID, closest(date >= conf_after))) |>
  mutate(
    start = if_else(date == first(date), score, NA),
    baseline = coalesce(start, change),
    .by = patID
  ) |>
  group_by(patID) |>
  fill(baseline) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(check = baseline == desired) |> # to check outcome
  relocate(desired, .before = baseline)  # to check outcome
#> # A tibble: 14 × 10
#>    patID   tmp date       score conf_after change start desired baseline check
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <date>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>
#>  1     1     1 2020-01-01   300 NA             NA   300     300      300 TRUE 
#>  2     1     2 2020-05-01   100 NA             NA    NA     300      300 TRUE 
#>  3     1     3 2020-06-01   100 NA             NA    NA     300      300 TRUE 
#>  4     1     4 2020-09-01   100 2020-07-30    100    NA     100      100 TRUE 
#>  5     1     5 2021-01-01   200 2020-07-30    100    NA     100      100 TRUE 
#>  6     1     6 2021-05-01   200 2021-04-01    200    NA     200      200 TRUE 
#>  7     2     1 2020-01-01   600 NA             NA   600     600      600 TRUE 
#>  8     2     2 2020-05-01   400 NA             NA    NA     600      600 TRUE 
#>  9     3     1 2020-01-01   300 NA             NA   300     300      300 TRUE 
#> 10     3     2 2020-02-01   200 NA             NA    NA     300      300 TRUE 
#> 11     3     3 2020-03-01   200 NA             NA    NA     300      300 TRUE 
#> 12     3     4 2020-06-01   100 2020-05-01    200    NA     200      200 TRUE 
#> 13     3     5 2020-10-01   400 2020-05-01    200    NA     200      200 TRUE 
#> 14     3     6 2021-04-01   300 2020-05-01    200    NA     300      200 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-29 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your input, that's an interesting approach. But it doesn't take into account that an increase or decrease needs to be confirmed at 90 days before it becomes the new baseline. 
If the score decreases from 300 to 200 (first decrease event), then up until 90 days after this event I need to still see a decrease compared to 300 (for example, a score of 100 after 45 days and again 100 after 90 days). The new baseline should be 200 (the minimal change that was confirmed). 
Example: score = c("300", "100", "50", "100", "200", "200"), the baseline cant become 50 at tmp 4. Hope it's clear!

Comment: Could you add patient 3 to your example df with the expected outcome?

Comment: I have added a patient 3 where the code does not result in the expected outcome. In this example, the baseline can never become 100 as this has not been confirmed at a following time point, and the baseline should be 300 until the decrease can be confirmed at time point 4.